# zend form submit button value not showing in zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Hi I have a zend form with this code in it

```
$field = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
$field->setAttrib('class', 'btn')->setlabel('Save');        

$this->addElement($field);
```

but the html comeing is:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" helper="formSubmit" value="" id="submit" name="submit">
```

can't figure out why is the value not showing up?

Answer (score 2):

```
$field->setAttrib('class', 'btn')->setLabel('Save');
```

please note the capital 'L' in `setLabel()` above

Comment: Hi rishi, i tried this code `->setLabel('Save')` but its still not showing the value in the submit.

Comment: Both setlabel and setLabel work, I've tested them (using your code) and they do. How do you display your form or this form input ?

Comment: My output does not get the 'helper="formSubmit"' bit, where does that come from ?

Answer (score 1):

Change type (default type="button" don't trigger form submit) to "submit". e.g.

```
$this->addElement('button', 'my_button', array(
    'label' => 'Click me',
    'class' => 'nice_button',
    'type' => 'submit'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the value? so use the setter:`$field->setValue('Save');`